# Can you invoke a function from a array?

Tags: vb.net

I have an Array that has multiple function calls in it but Visual Basic gives an error that Expression is not a method when trying to invoke my function by array position. Is there any way to have an array of functions that allow invoking by array position.

`Dim Array()() As Object = New Object()() {
    New Object() {0},
    New Object() {0, FunctionA()}
}`

Sample Code of the structure of my array. I am trying to get it to where when I type 
`Array(1)(1)` it invokes Function A

Comment: There is no way we can answer your question without at least seeing *some* code. Can you put a delegate (wrapper for a method) in an array? Yes you can. Can you invoke these delegates directly from the array? Yes you can.

Comment: Your code example makes little sense and provides no real way to envision a way in which what you describe could be used in a real-world scenario.  That said, where you have `FunctionA()` in that code is a call to `FunctionA` that is executed when the array is created.  Is that actually what you want?  It seems like what you actually want is a reference to that method that you can invoke latter, in which case you need `AddressOf FunctionA` in order to create a delegate.

Comment: @jmcilhinney am I also right in thinking that if the OP decides to use the `Delegate` idea, then the return type for all the functions must be the same? I suppose they could all return `Object` types, but I suspect that the gnarly mess that creates would be be very open to errors.

Comment: @DavidWilson, the actual return type of the methods could be anything you want, but you'd have to invoke them via the `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` method, in which case you'd get an `Object` reference returned to you anyway.  You'd then have to work out what to do with it yourself in each case.  As you say, that leads to a bit of a gnarly mess.  I would see such mechanisms as more suitable for a `Sub` than a `Function`, so there is nothing returned so no need to determine what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/delegates/), here is a way you can set an array of delegate functions and pass them to another method (if you wish) in VB.NET:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Delegate Sub delegateSub()

    Public Sub func1()
        MsgBox("I AM FUNC1")
    End Sub

    Public Sub func2()
        MsgBox("I AM FUNC2")
    End Sub

    Public Sub func3()
        MsgBox("I AM FUNC3")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim functions As delegateSub() = {New delegateSub(AddressOf func1), New delegateSub(AddressOf func2), New delegateSub(AddressOf func3)}
        InvokeDelegates(functions)
    End Sub


    Private Sub InvokeDelegates(ByVal functions() As delegateSub)
        For Each funcy As delegateSub In functions
            funcy.Invoke()
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```